# ServiceMonitor not found in monitoring.coreos.com/v1

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator

I am using `kubeadm` to deploy single node kubernetes 1.11 cluster.
I am unable to find `servicemonitor` resources.

```
➜  kube-prometheus git:(master) ✗ kubectl get servicemonitor
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "servicemonitor"

➜  kube-prometheus git:(master) ✗ kubectl create -f manifests/prometheus-serviceMonitor.yaml
error: unable to recognize "manifests/prometheus-serviceMonitor.yaml": no matches for kind "ServiceMonitor" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"
```

How do I enable `servicemonitor` with `kubeadm`?

Comment: Check on what K8s versions support that resource.

Answer (score 9):

The `ServiceMonitor` resource not part of Kubernetes itself. It is a custom resource which is part of the Prometheus operator [as described here](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator#customresourcedefinitions).

Make sure that you have installed the Prometheus operator (including the custom resources) beforehand to enable creating a ServiceMonitor object.

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl create -f manifests/prometheus-serviceMonitor.yaml`  try to create resource type of ServiceMontor for prometheus. But you haven't created that  custom resource type yet. So first create CustomResource ServiceMonitor by using [this](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/charts/crds/crds/crd-servicemonitors.yaml) custom resource definition(CRD). you can use following command

`kubectl create -f manifests/0prometheus-operator-0servicemonitorCustomResourceDefinition.yaml`

But if you are trying to put up [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/contrib/kube-prometheus) or any other sub project of [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator). You can deploy the kube-prometheus stack by running all deployments in folder level as below.

```
kubectl create -f manifests/
```

Comment: The link is not working anymore. can you update it?

Comment: the CRD has been moved here: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/main/manifests/setup/prometheus-operator-0servicemonitorCustomResourceDefinition.yaml

Answer (score 2):

serviceMonitor kind is not default in kubernetes cluster and it can be installed in the cluster by

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/main/bundle.yaml

This will be install few more other components, create this in separate namespace and remove  it !!